# How do you make a NEAR account with locked tokens show the proper amount unlocked?

Tags: nearprotocol

Some account balances don't appear to be updating to reflect changes in balances due to lockups.  Is there a way to ping the account and get it to update properly?

`check_transfer_vote` seems useful here to get the `view` method to show the right info.